# Imagem não aparece no Flatlist React Native

Tags: array, lista, imagem, react-native, requirejs

Olá, eu estou tentando montar uma lista com com alguns elementos dentro dela mas o elemento de imagem não aparece mas retorna o tamanho certo da imagem.

Eu criei um array com os dados que quero mostrar, depois criei uma função que retorna o JSX da forma que eu quero e recebe tanto a imagem quanto os outros textos como parâmetro e por fim utilizei ele no **flatlist** da classe que usa essa função.

**O array que recebe as imagens com require:**

```js
const DATA = [

{
    image: require('./luz.png'),
    id: '3',
    title: 'Parabens você economizou \n luz em sua casa ',
    pontos: '75 pts'
},
{
    image: require('./recycle.png'),
    title: 'Hoje você ajudou a tirar \nlixo dos oceanos !',
    pontos: '95 pts',
    id: '1',
},
{
    image: require('./cesta.png'),
    id: '2',
    title: 'Comida orgânica ajuda \n o meio ambiente !',
    pontos: '55 pts'
},
{
    image: require('./cesta.png'),
    id: '4',
    title: 'Comida orgânica ajuda \n o meio ambiente !',
    pontos: '55 pts'
},
{
    image: require('./cesta.png'),
    id: '5',
    title: 'Comida orgânica ajuda \n o meio ambiente !',
    pontos: '55 pts'
},
]
```

**Aqui a função que trabalha os elementos em JSX:**

```js
function Item({ title, image,pontos }) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Image source={{image}} style={{ width: 75, height: 99, }}></Image>
        <Text style={styles.descriTe}>{title}</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18,fontWeight: 'bold',color: '#598fe1',marginLeft: 30, textAlign: 'right' ,textAlignVertical: 'center',}}>{pontos}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

**A classe em que uso a flatlist:**

```js
class Principal extends React.Component {



    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {

        return{
        headerTitle: (            
            <View 
                style={{
                marginLeft: 65,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                backgroundColor: '#598fe1',
                borderRadius: 50,
                marginTop: 20,
                }}>
            <ImageBackground source={require('./slothH.png')} style={{
                    width: 66,
                    height: 77,
                    marginTop: 10,
                    }}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
        ),  

        headerLeft: (
            <View>
            </View>
        ),
        headerRight: <SinalMais navigation={navigation} />,
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#598fe1',
        }
    }
    }

    state = { currentUser: null }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { currentUser } = firebase.auth()
        this.setState({ currentUser })
    }

  render() {
      const { currentUser } = this.state
  return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.containerTopPrin}>
                <Text style={styles.tituloPag}>
                Olá {currentUser && currentUser.email}!
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.descriTe}>
                Aqui são as coisas que já fez {"\n"}
                para ajudar o mundo !
                </Text>

            </View>



            <View style={styles.containerPrin}>
                <ScrollView>
                    <FlatList
                        data={DATA} 
                        renderItem={({item}) => (
                        <Item image={item.image} title={item.title} pontos={item.pontos} />) }
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    />
                </ScrollView>               
            </View>

//e o código continua daqui..
```

Tanto no Expo quanto na própria build ele não esta mostrando a imagem.

Comment: Passe apenas o caminho no Objeto. Daí onde você renderiza chama o require com o a variável do caminho da imagem.

Comment: hmm ele da erro 500 quando eu faço isso, parece que não é permitido fazer isso.. invalid call na função require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chama a image assim...

```
   const DATA = [
    {
    image: source={require('./luz.png')},
    id: '3',
    [...]
```

Tenta puxar da seguinte forma...

```
<Item image={{uri: item.image}} [...]
```

Comment: No array eu consegui so com o require, mas o erro foi que a imagem não pode ser passada como propriedade, eu simplesmente tirei a função Item e joguei a imagem direto na Flatlist, que foi o que voce sugeriu ali ... valeu !